# Spanish rebus puzzle

Tags: rebus, language

[image]

I need help in solving this picture riddle in Spanish language.

Comment: Welcome to PSE! This kind of puzzle using images is called a rebus; I hope you don't mind me adding the appropriate tag.

Comment: Would you care to say where it comes from?

Comment: received it in an email

Comment: Is there something interesting in this that you created two different accounts and posted the question and hints under different ones?

Comment: Is this rebus meant to be in English? I mean, you have a Spanish name and the first picture could mean "valoro" (Val Kilmer + Gold) and the last two coule mean "paso" (Pennsylvania + so). And Germany is "de", of course.

Comment: sorry just received word this is in spanish, you are correct M Oehm